# how can I make Google Guice to automatically detect a binding?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I understand how to inject a single dependency using Google Guice. 
The following snippets are from the Guice site.

To code a configuration the code would be

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    bind(TransactionLog.class).to(DatabaseTransactionLog.class);
    bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).to(PaypalCreditCardProcessor.class);
  }
}
```

The component which use the dependencies to be injected shuold looks like the following:

```
class BillingService {
  private final CreditCardProcessor processor;
  private final TransactionLog transactionLog;

  @Inject
  BillingService(CreditCardProcessor processor, 
      TransactionLog transactionLog) {
    this.processor = processor;
    this.transactionLog = transactionLog;
  }

  public Receipt chargeOrder(PizzaOrder order, CreditCard creditCard) {
    ...
  }
}
```

FInally, the client code would use Guice to inject the dependencies where needed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());

    BillingService billingService = injector.getInstance(BillingService.class);
    ...
  }
```

My question is:

Is there a built-in feature in Guice to inject not only -for example- BillingService.class but another different implementation ***in runtime***?

I think I can implement the variation of the different classes to be injected thru reflection or some manual mechanism like reading a configuration file to indicate which class to inject but I still want to know if this can be done from Guice itself.

Comment: Under what condition would there be a different implementation? What entity decides that? Maybe http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods

Comment: Lets say the behaviour has to change dinamically and we wouldn't to deploy again. Provide Methods are a good option. The business rules would be hard coded in the Provide Method with a default implementation as a result when no rule apply ... that would be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make BillingService an interface and bind a different implementation of it decided in runtime in Module's configure method.

Comment: Remember that `configure()` runs exactly once on Injector creation. If the binding is defined once, choose it in `configure`, but if it may change after initial configuration you'll probably have to put it in a Provider or a @Provides method.

Comment: What if the choosing depends on some business parameters?